# HTML Anchor to File URI that contains pound sign (#) won't open in IE11 - if you use target _blank

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, file-uri

Yes, I am encoding #.

If you have a network share you can use, you can play along.  Do the following:

1. Create two folders on your network share.  One with a # in it, one without.  My folder names are: **z#Bernie2016** and **zBernie2016**
2. Inside each folder put one file in it with some text in it or something (I just slapped together some simple html files that said **Hi!**)  I named my file **zFeelTheBern.html**
3. Put this in a file (extenion is .html) on your desktop -- Sorry, you will have to change brackets to less than and greater than signs (I cannot believe I can't figure out, in 15 minutes, how to put html code in this post.  Annoying.  Even after reading a thread on stackexchange about it.  Yes, I used the pre-code stuff.  Sure I can code whole systems and architect everything - html in a post? Naaah!):

   [HTML]

   [BODY]

   [a Href="file://///Shared-server-name/z%23Bernie2016/zFeelTheBern.html" target="_blank"]file:///// with %23[/a][br]

   [a Href="file://///Shared-server-name/zBernie2016/zFeelTheBern.html" target="_blank"]file:///// without %23[/a][br]

   [a Href="file:///\\Shared-server-name\z%23Bernie2016\zFeelTheBern.html" target="_blank"]file:///\\ with %23[/a][br]

   [a Href="file:///\\Shared-server-name\zBernie2016\zFeelTheBern.html" target="_blank"]file:///\\ without %23[/a][br]

   [/BODY]

   [/HTML]

I opened this html file from my desktop and here are my results:

**Firefox** (I'm running 43.0.4)

all 4 open fine.  No issues.  In the address bar, I see either:

file://///Shared-server-name/zBernie2016/zFeelTheBern.html

or

file://///Shared-server-name/z%23Bernie2016/zFeelTheBern.html

**IE11**

The # folder won't open (I get "This page can't be displayed"), yet the one without will.

IE loves to muck with the file URI, as this is what I see in the address bar that works:

\\Shared-server-name\zBernie2016\zFeelTheBern.html

and what doesn't work:

\\Shared-server-name\z

It just hits the # (or %23) and stops.  IE also loves to remove the file:/// at the front and reverse the slashes.

EDIT: It looks like the target in the anchor is hurting things.  If I remove the target = _blank stuff, it works fine.  I *want* that though.